# FB.feed dialog looks different depending on login

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

This question is related to the question linked below, but instead deals with the interactive console included with the Facebook SDK:

[Facebook Post to wall FB.Feed issue in Unity Facebook SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056390/facebook-post-to-wall-fb-feed-issue-in-unity-facebook-sdk)

I have two screenshots to show the issue I'm having. This first screenshot is the FB.Feed dialog I get the first time I allow the app permission to post to my wall. It also shows if I invoke the dialog and I've given NO permission for it to post.

[image]

This particular dialog has trouble displaying the app's icon. It also grays out the entire screen, and doesn't allow any click throughs to the Unity app running, which is ideal but is different than the behavior of the other dialog, which I'll show next.

Here is the second screenshot, taken after refreshing the application page. The background app is not grayed out, and in my application, you can click through to the app in the background and interact with it, right through the dialog box. Obviously, this is not ideal.

[image]

So my questions are, what's causing these dialogs to change, and how can I make the API show the one that I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one happens only when the person first allows your app.  First time a person allows your app they will see the normal javascript dialogs.  However, if they come back to your game, they will see the second dialog that occurs inside your game.

We prevent a normal click-through in our dialogs that should be enforced by Unity's Modal Window: https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.ModalWindow.html

However, it looks like Unity has a bug on their end that might clicks through.  I've messaged Unity and they are now aware of the issue.  Thanks for reporting that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to always use the javascript dialog in this case? Some kind of override?

Comment: If you look at the `FB` class you'll notice that it really just wraps around the `IFacebook` interface.  You can set the underlying object `IFacebook.DialogMode` to either 0 or 1.  0 = the in game dialogs.  1 = the js dialgos

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. Can you verify I'm changing the right line?
        public override int DialogMode
        {
            get { return 1; }
            set { ; }
        }
The return 1 was return 0. I switched it to 1.
I don't see dialogmode referenced anywhere else tho. I do see it being set in iOSFacebook, but that's not where this issue resides. 
Any help is appreciated, thanks.